# Files to folder without folders

Tags: windows, batch-file

My current .bat file organizes any/all files into a folder with the same name:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*.eng*) do (
  set file=%%a
  ren "!file!" "!file:_=!"
)
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /o:-n ^| findstr /iv "folderize.bat"') do (
md "%%~na" 2>nul
move "%%a" "%%~na"
)
```

This works perfectly, except that it includes folders as well.  What can I do to exclude ANY/ALL folders???

Comment: Change `dir /b /o:-n` to `dir /b /a:-d /o:-n`...

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks!